# To allow remote connections to SQL Server, do we have to start the SQL Browser service?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008

To allow remote connections to SQL Server, do we have to start the SQL Browser service?

Is it basically the service that binds the server to a particular port, i.e. it is a must?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, SQL Browser is only required if your client doesn't know the specific port to connect to and is trying to connect via a Named Instance on a server that contains multiple Named Instances.